# Compare two rows in a data frame after groupby and perform operations

Tags: python, pandas, compare, pandas-groupby

I have two different csv files, I have merged them into a single data frame and grouped according to the 'class_name' column. The group by works as intended but I dont know how to perform the operation by comparing the groups against one other.  From r1.csv the class algebra has gone down by 5 students, so I want -5, calculus has increased by 5 so it has to +5, this has to be added as a new column in a separate data frame. Same with date arithmetics.

This is what I tried so far

```
import pandas as pd
report_1_df=pd.read_csv('r1.csv')
report_2_df=pd.read_csv('r2.csv')
for group,elements in pd.concat([report_1_df, report_2_df], axis=0, sort=False).groupby('class_name'):
    print(elements)
```

I can see that my group by works, I tried `.sum()` `.diff()` but none seem to do what I want, what can I do here. Thanks.

r1.csv

```
class_name,student_count,start_time,end_time
algebra,15,"2019,Dec,08","2019,Dec,09"
calculus,10,"2019,Dec,08","2019,Dec,09"
statistics,12,"2019,Dec,08","2019,Dec,09"
```

r2.csv

```
class_name,student_count,start_time,end_time
calculus,15,"2019,Dec,09","2019,Dec,10"
algebra,10,"2019,Dec,09","2019,Dec,10"
trigonometry,12,"2019,Dec,09","2019,Dec,10"
```

Needed

```
class_name,student_count,student_count_change,start_time,start_time_delay,end_time,end_time_delay
algebra,10,-5,"2019,Dec,09",1,"2019,Dec,10",1
calculus,15,5,"2019,Dec,09",1,"2019,Dec,10",1
statistics,12,-12,"2019,Dec,08",0,"2019,Dec,09",0
trigonometry,12,12,"2019,Dec,09",0,"2019,Dec,10",0
```

Comment: The `student_count` column in result should be from r1 or r2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's a more direct way, but you can start by appending missing data on both your dfs:

```
classes = (df1["class_name"].append(df2["class_name"])).unique()

def fill_data(df):
    for i in np.setdiff1d(classes, df["class_name"].values):
        df.loc[df.shape[0]] = [i, 0, *df.iloc[0,2:].values]
    return df

df1 = fill_data(df1)
df2 = fill_data(df2)
```

With the missing classes filled, now you can use `groupby` to assign a new column for the difference and lastly `drop_duplicates`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

df["diff"] = df.groupby("class_name")["student_count"].diff().fillna(df["student_count"])

print (df.drop_duplicates("class_name",keep="last"))

     class_name  student_count   start_time     end_time  diff
4      calculus             15  2019,Dec,09  2019,Dec,10   5.0
5       algebra             10  2019,Dec,09  2019,Dec,10  -5.0
6  trigonometry             12  2019,Dec,09  2019,Dec,10  12.0
7    statistics              0  2019,Dec,09  2019,Dec,10 -12.0
```